# wc_get_template_part doesnt display the content

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, ajax, jquery, rest-api

hello guys when i try to loop products it's just display the div but not product info

the image of the result
[image: image of result]

```
function stsearch_products($data) {
  $args = array(
      'post_type'     => 'product', 
      'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'order'         => 'ASC' // ASC
  );
  $args['s'] = $data['search-title'];
  

  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  ob_start();
  if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :

      do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );

      woocommerce_product_loop_start(); 


          while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :

              $loop->the_post();

              wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );

          endwhile;
  
      woocommerce_product_loop_end(); 


      do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' ); 


  else :

      do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );

  endif; 

 
  wp_reset_postdata(); 
  return ob_get_clean();

}
```

Comment: REST API never renders content. Are you sure that you're on the right URL?

Comment: WooCommerce and other 3rd party plugin/theme dev support is offtopic here, you need to ask at their official routes or in a WooCommerce community

Comment: @KarolínaVyskočilová yes i'm sure and link its correct. but why it's never renders content?

Comment: @TomJNowell okay thanks sir